Android error "Tag Was Lost" in XIAOMI only
I am developing an application with NFC and an NFC TAG (ST25). When I send more than 13 bytes with the nfcV.transceive() command, I receive the error "TAG WAS LOST", but it only occurs on the XIAOMI smartphone, on the others it works correctly.
    private fun readTag(intent: Intent) {

        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED == intent.action
            || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED == intent.action
            || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED == intent.action) {
            val tag: Tag? = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG, Tag::class.java)

            if (tag != null)  {
                val st25 = ST25DVTag.get(tag)
                st25?.connect()
                val stringToConvert = etDataToWrite.text.toString()
                val messageBytes = stringToConvert.toByteArray(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
                try {
                    st25.WriteMB(messageBytes.size - 1, messageBytes)
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR Write tag NFC: $e",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Log.e("NFC ERROR","OK write tag NFC: $e")
                } finally {
                    try {
                        st25.close()
                    } catch (e: IOException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
}


    fun WriteMB(size: Int , data:ByteArray): ByteArray {
        val writecommandLength = 4 + data.size // Calculate total length including data
        val writecommand = ByteArray(writecommandLength)
        // Copy ST25DV_REQUEST_HEADER, 0xCA, IC_MFG_CODE, and size
        System.arraycopy(byteArrayOf(ST25DV_REQUEST_HEADER,0xAA.toByte(),IC_MFG_CODE,size.toByte()),0, writecommand, 0, 4)
        // Copy the data to the end of writecommand
        System.arraycopy(data, 0, writecommand, 4, data.size)
        var lenmax = tag.maxTransceiveLength
        return safeTransceive(writecommand)
    }

    private fun safeTransceive(command: ByteArray): ByteArray {
        var nTry = 0
        var errorCode = COMMAND_OK
        do {
            val response = tag.transceive(command)
            errorCode = response[0]
            Log.d("Transceive","ErrorCode:"+errorCode)
            if (errorCode == COMMAND_OK)
                return response.copyOfRange(1,response.size)
            else {
                nTry++
                Thread.sleep(COMMAND_DELAY)
            }
        } while (nTry < COMMAND_RETRY)
        throw ST25DVException("IOError: code " + errorCode)
    }

When the "messageBytes.size" bigger that 13 bytes, the error occur.
Is there a XIAOMI hardware problem? How can I solve this problem?
Thanks

You get maxTransceiveLength but don't do anything with it, the XIAOMI hardware might have smaller buffers, you should check that your are not trying to Transceive more than possible. Also you don't show this part of the code but commonly when using the Old NFC API that uses Intent's people do NFC I/O on the main thread which blocks and might cause errors that lead to Tag Lost errors. Using Intents also leads to lots of errors with real users when writing to NFC, suggest that you use the enableReaderMode NFC API instead.

I'm running in a separate thread, not the main one. maxTransceiveLength always returns the value 253, so my 'Transceive' is always less than this value.
With 'enableReaderMode' the error occurs the same when writing more than 13 bytes.
Running the APP on another smartphone, the write operation does not return any errors, only on the XIAOMI.
